# How to setup i18n translated URL routes in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, routes, internationalization, next.js

I am using [Next.js i18n-routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing) to setup multi-language website. This works perfectly. If I create a file in `/pages/about.js` this will create URLs based on my locale settings, for example:

- EN -> `/about`
- DE -> `/de/about`
- ES -> `/es/about`

That is all fine.

What if I want to have a translated URL routes for each language? I am stuck on how to set this up...

- EN -> `/about`
- DE -> `/de/uber-uns`
- ES -> `/es/nosotros`

?

Comment: Great question. If you already found a better way to handle route translation, please let us know.

Answer (score 31):

You can achieve translated URL routes by leveraging [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#rewrites-with-i18n-support) in your `next.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en', 'de', 'es'],
        defaultLocale: 'en'
    },
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/de/uber-uns',
                destination: '/de/about',
                locale: false // Use `locale: false` so that the prefix matches the desired locale correctly
            },
            {
                source: '/es/nosotros',
                destination: '/es/about',
                locale: false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

Furthermore, if you want a consistent routing behaviour during client-side navigations, you can create a wrapper around the `next/link` component to ensure the translated URLs are displayed.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Link from 'next/link'

const pathTranslations = {
    de: {
        '/about': '/uber-uns'
    },
    es: {
        '/about': '/sobrenos'
    }
}

const TranslatedLink = ({ href, children }) => {
    const { locale } = useRouter()
    // Get translated route for non-default locales
    const translatedPath = pathTranslations[locale]?.[href] 
    // Set `as` prop to change displayed URL in browser
    const as = translatedPath ? `/${locale}${translatedPath}` : undefined

    return (
        <Link href={href} as={as}> 
            {children}
        </Link>
    )
}

export default TranslatedLink
```

Then use `TranslatedLink` instead of `next/link` in your code.

```js
<TranslatedLink href='/about'>
    <a>Go to About page</a>
</TranslatedLink>
```

Note that you could reuse the `pathTranslations` object to dynamically generate the `rewrites` array in the `next.config.js` and have a single source of truth for the translated URLs.

Comment: I was looking into rewrites, but this seems a bit clumsy to manage rewrites for 9 languages and 100s of pages. Also then you have dynamic routes which makes things increasingly complicated with rewrites.

Comment: Definitely - this is a simple solution that wouldn't scale that well. You may want to look into adding a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) for a more complex and scalable solution.

Comment: @PrimozRome Did you manage to find an work around for this? I'm currently encountering the same issue.

Comment: @Jurrian there is no nice solution to this yet. What we are doing now is using router catch all feture and then using custom logic to route this correctly: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes.

Comment: I wrote an article to illustrate this

https://dev.to/martinratinaud/internationalize-nextjs-urls-with-next-translate-49d8

Answer (score 2):

For a more scalable solution check this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-translate-routes

With this you can keep one json file for your main urls and translations and also has a  component for making i18n links easier

Comment: This doesnt work for Next 13 new app dir, as of today 10-05-2023, but they are working on it. Anyone know a solution for next 13 with the new app dir?