# Next js rewrites not working for i18n routes

Tags: next.js

I'm having some issues with i18n rewrites in next js.

Inside of my `next.config.js` I have the following

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "nl"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },

  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/nl/about",
        destination: "/nl/over-ons",
        locale: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Now I have the following two pages

```
about.tsx

index.tsx
```

Inside of my `index.tsx` file I have a single `<Link>` tag :

```
<Link href="/about">About us</Link>
```

Now when I change my browser language from EN to NL my route is prefixed with `nl` so that works fine, the problem is that the `about` page in nl never changes it's url to `over-ons` it always remains `about`.

Not sure what's going wrong in such a simple example?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to setup i18n translated URL routes in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68731057/1870780)?

Comment: Hey, tried that but it seems to have some issues, in terms of scalability, also when refreshing a page using that method it will give a 404 because next js is unable to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is already late for you, but this might still help others.

What you want to achieve is maybe `redirect`, not `rewrite`.
Learn more about [rewrite](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites) and [redirect](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/redirects).

Simply change your `rewrites` to `redirect` like the example below should fix your issue:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "nl"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },

  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/nl/about",
        destination: "/nl/over-ons",
        locale: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```