# latin and non latin multi language url with next.js

Tags: next.js, multilingual, i18next, non-latin

We have to build `react` web with `next.js` and problem with multilanguage url. Our goal is same content for diffrent language have diffrend url slug. For example `www.tld.com/blog` for blog page in english post list, `www.tld.com/блог` for blog page in mongolian blog post.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to setup i18n translated URL routes in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68723485/how-to-setup-i18n-translated-url-routes-in-next-js)?

Comment: nope, without special language prefix just the native languare slug. for example
www.tld.com/about-us vs www.tld.com/über-uns they are same pages but first one ist in english, the second is in german.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next.js` [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) to transform a subpath like `/blog` vs `/блог` to url parameters such as `?lang=en` for example, or a different page possible.

Also - just figured this out - if you want static pages with non-latin characters, you can use the url escaped notation in file names and redirects, so a file named `%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D.js` would route to a `/שלום` url

Hope this helps!