# Language & url change in headless CMS

Tags: wordpress, next.js, internationalization, headless-cms, dynamic-routing

I'm using Wordrpess as headlessCMS, nextJS, graphQL.

When i get my menu from wordpress it has links in this way 
For ENG:
"/about-us"
For PL:
"/o-nas"

My goal is to have one template in my files, for example "/pages/about.js"; and then when user enters "/about-us" or "/o-nas" then "/pages/about.js" file is used (inside it, by useRouter I can detect  if user is /en or /pl and then make specific query for data).

How can I create this kind of idk. 'redirection'? I tried using  but i wasn't able to make anything working

- https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/custom-paths/?fbclid=IwAR1k5T5AI5hX60ep4coXtOwUpXirNfc5W4-5NzVv-y0G7wLoPPKPAL4xNv4
- https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

Can anyone help me or provide some kind of working example?

Comment: I think that I finally find the answer for my question.

[here is the answer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-translate-routes)

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [How to setup i18n translated URL routes in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68723485/how-to-setup-i18n-translated-url-routes-in-next-js)?

Comment: It would be good too; but the first comment to my question was that one that solved my problem ;)