# NextJS internationalized routing (localized slugs)

Tags: routes, next.js, localization, internationalization

I have a website using i18n for internationalize routing, which works properly, but now we would like to translate, localize the slugs as well.

[image: page structure]

So for example, we have this route */integrations-and-plugins*
Eg: 3 locales, en de and hu
We want that:

- /en/integrations-and-plugins/
- /de/integrationen-und-plugins/
- /hu/integraciok-es-pluginok/

(+additionally it has a integrations-and-plugins/*id, but does not really matter)

Here is my next config relating part:

```
const bundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: !!process.env.BUNDLE_ANALYZE,
})

module.exports = bundleAnalyzer({
  images: {
    domains: ['cdn.builder.io'],
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        headers: [
          // this will allow site to be framed under builder.io for wysiwyg editing
          {
            key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
            value: 'frame-ancestors https://*.builder.io https://builder.io',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/hu/integracios-es-ellenorzesi/',
        destination: '/hu/integrations-and-plugins/',
        locale: false,
      },
      {
        source: '/de/integracios-es-ellenorzesi/',
        destination: '/de/integrationen-und-plugins/',
        locale: false,
      },
     
    ]
  },
  // async redirects() { //WE DON'T WANT TO USE REDIRECTS BECAUSE OF SEO PURPOSES
  //   return [
  //     {
  //       source: '/hu/integracios-es-ellenorzesi/',
           destination: '/hu/integrations-and-plugins/',
  //       permanent: true,
  //       locale: false,
  //     },
  //     {
  //       source: '/de/integracios-es-ellenorzesi/',
           destination: '/de/integrationen-und-plugins/',
  //       permanent: true,
  //       locale: false,
  //     },
  //   ]
  // },
  i18n: {
    locales: ['default', 'en', 'hu', 'de', 'cz', 'eu', 'sl'],
    defaultLocale: 'default',
    localeDetection: true,
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
})
```

As far as I know, this feature is currently not supported by Next.js (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18485)

And with rewrites I can only achieve that the content will be the correct one, but the url will stay the same, and although redirects would work for changing the url, but we don't want to redirects, because of SEO, and it is simply not the best option for this.

Hope someone had the same issue, and can help me to figure out the best way to translate the url slugs:

Comment: Shouldn't the first `rewrites` be `{ source: '/hu/integraciok-es-pluginok/', destination: '/hu/integrations-and-plugins/', locale: false }` and the second be `{ source: '/de/integrationen-und-plugins/', destination: '/de/integrations-and-plugins/', locale: false }`? You want each translated route to rewrite to the actual non-translated one.

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [How to setup i18n translated URL routes in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68723485/how-to-setup-i18n-translated-url-routes-in-next-js)?

Comment: actually I want that the non-translated one will rewrite to the translated one. So if I write /hu/integrations-and-plugins the url will be rewritten to /hu/integraciok-es-pluginok

hope it makes sense

Comment: That would require a redirect I'm afraid.

Comment: what other options are available for localizing url paths?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think that translated slugs were solved in Next.js APP folder.

The official recommendation is to use `[lang]` root segment and bunch of rewrites/middleware which is IMO overhead and comes against the benefits of static file-based routing.

I would recommend to utilize static routes = generate all your translated slugs in advance.

I have created a tiny lib for that. Feel free to check it it might help.

https://github.com/svobik7/next-roots

Comment: this looks promising, I will give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

There's an issue topic related to your question on the NextJS repository that might help you to follow the community approaches: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18485