# Next.js i18n translate URL occurs 404 error?

Tags: javascript, next.js, i18next

I'm making a multilingual service using next-i18next.
I wanted some of my routes translate too for instance:

**EN**: `/contact` => default language

**IT**:  `/fa/ارتباط-با-ما` => second language

For this purpose, I used translated URL routes by [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in my `next.config.js` file.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');
const nextConfig = {
  i18n,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/ارتباط-با-ما',
        destination: '/contact-us',
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I created my navigation with this guide:‌ [How to setup i18n translated URL routes in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68731057/11001615)

you can check out my code there https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-thwgak

**Problem**:‌ Go to the home page then change the language to Farsi after that go to the contact page you see so far so good but when you reload the page on the contact page you get a 404 error.

Is this a bug or am I wrong? Where did I go wrong? Any idea?

ps question: what do rewrites affect SEO?

Comment: have you tried adding ```source: /fa/ارتباط-با-ما``` as as source, or passing ```locale: false``` to the object?

Comment: @maxeth yes, of course, I've tried everything on the internet

Comment: Maybe try opening an issue on the Next Github, because if the path you visit is being correctly entered as a source, the server should always rewrite the response to the destination, even after a page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `ارتباط-با-ما` gets URL encoded when it reaches the Next.js server, so you have to also encode your `source` value accordingly for it to match the rewrite rule.

```js
const nextConfig = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: `/fa/${encodeURIComponent('ارتباط-با-ما')}`,
                destination: '/fa/contact-us',
                locale: false
            }
        ];
    }
};
```